# How to run a .NET Core 3.1.3 x86 App in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, x86, dockerfile

I have a .NET Core 3.1.3 Web API project that is built as x86.  It has to be x86 because it makes use of an x86 C++ DLL via dllimport.  Outside of Docker the application runs as expected.  However, it fails immediately as soon as I add Windows Docker support.  I believe from SO research that it fails because Microsoft does not provide any x86 base image for .NET Core.  The default Windows Docker base image is currently mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903.

I've tried using mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909 as the base image, but I then get an error saying "Unable to start program: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe.'"  I assume this is because this exe does not exist on the base image used.  And, presumably for x86 "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" would actually be required.

My current Dockerfile is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WAPTCoreWebService/WAPTCoreWebService.csproj", "WAPTCoreWebService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WAPTCoreWebService/WAPTCoreWebService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WAPTCoreWebService"
RUN dotnet build "WAPTCoreWebService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WAPTCoreWebService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WAPTCoreWebService.dll"]
```

Am I interpreting this error correctly.  If not, what does it mean?  If so, how do I add support to build an x86 version of my .NET Core app in this image?  Do I need to download and run dotnet-runtime-3.1.3-win-x86.exe somehow?  If so, how?

**UPDATE** 4/29/2020

Based on Matt Thalman's answer I have built a custom image to include x86 version of the .NET Core SDK.  The Docker file is:

```
# escape=`

# Installer image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909 AS installer

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Retrieve .NET Core SDK
RUN $dotnet_sdk_version = '3.1.201'; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile dotnet.zip https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/$dotnet_sdk_version/dotnet-sdk-$dotnet_sdk_version-win-x86.zip; `
    $dotnet_sha512 = '48aa1afaf7a52effb367bbb14a66e2c3bf8da468025795daf0fa0d18e3b9650ba3bd23800c9965a4d4ec1d891afecbce51b2487730f1b0d6040ee7cb73a15ec6'; `
    if ((Get-FileHash dotnet.zip -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $dotnet_sha512) { `
        Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
        exit 1; `
    }; `
    `
    Expand-Archive dotnet.zip -DestinationPath dotnet; `
    Remove-Item -Force dotnet.zip

# Install PowerShell global tool
RUN $powershell_version = '7.0.0'; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile PowerShell.Windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg https://pwshtool.blob.core.windows.net/tool/$powershell_version/PowerShell.Windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg; `
    $powershell_sha512 = '1980da63a4f6017235e7af810bfda66be8fa53d0475d147a8219a36c76a903af99adb6cd5309e3dadc610389ae3525bca1ca2d30e7a991640e924334fd4e4638'; `
    if ((Get-FileHash PowerShell.Windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $powershell_sha512) { `
        Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
        exit 1; `
    }; `
    `
    \dotnet\dotnet tool install --add-source . --tool-path \powershell --version $powershell_version PowerShell.Windows.x64; `
    \dotnet\dotnet nuget locals all --clear; `
    Remove-Item -Force PowerShell.Windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg; `
    Remove-Item -Path \powershell\.store\powershell.windows.x64\$powershell_version\powershell.windows.x64\$powershell_version\powershell.windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg -Force

# SDK image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909

ENV `
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true `
    # Enable correct mode for dotnet watch (only mode supported in a container)
    DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true `
    # Skip extraction of XML docs - generally not useful within an image/container - helps performance
    NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip `
    # PowerShell telemetry for docker image usage
    POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL=PSDocker-DotnetCoreSDK-NanoServer-1909

# In order to set system PATH, ContainerAdministrator must be used
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\powershell"
USER ContainerUser

COPY --from=installer ["/dotnet", "/Program Files (x86)/dotnet"]

COPY --from=installer ["/powershell", "/Program Files/powershell"]

# Trigger first run experience by running arbitrary cmd
RUN dotnet help
```

This builds just fine and the `dotnet help` command at the end executes correctly.

I changed my application Dockerfile to use this custom image as the base image and that also build fine.  When I run this from Visual Studio 2019 I get the same error as I did above ("Unable to start program: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe.'").  Why is VS still trying to use the x64 entry point.  The project is being built to target the x86 platform, and the resulting images seem fine.

I created a container based on the application image and `CMD`ed into that and confirmed all the files were where they were expected to be, and even ran `dotnet applicationName.dll` from the command line and the application started OK.

When I attempt to run from Visual Studio, it attempts to run the image via:

`docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\Valued Customer\onecoremsvsmon\16.5.0102.0:C:\remote_debugger:ro" -v "C:\Users\Valued Customer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\Valued Customer\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro" -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -P --name WAPTCoreWebService_1 --entrypoint C:\remote_debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe waptcorewebservice /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn /nowowwarn /fallbackloadremotemanagedpdbs /timeout:2147483646 /LogDebuggeeOutputToStdOut`

The entrypoint is pointing to an x64 application (msvsmon.exe).  Could this be the issue with running from VS?

Comment: I simply not able to run Invoke-WebRequest with this image (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909). It always fails with "remote name could not be resolved". However this image (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8) is better but im not able to set any ENV variables there. Am i missing any updates for this solution above?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? It is mandatory for you to build your app using windows? Where are you deploying your net apps?

Answer (score 1):

This is an imperfect answer, but I did manage to get a x86 .NET Core Web API that depends on a VC++ x86 DLL up and running on Azure Kubernetes Service.  Basically I have three stages:

1. Build a custom image based on mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 that add the C++ Redistributable 2015 x86;
2. Another image is created based on 1. that adds the .NET Core x86 SDK, and;
3. A final image is created based on 2. that adds my application code.

The three Dockerfiles are included below.  Next I'll be looking to consolidate this into a single Dockerfile.

**Add C++ Redist x86: waptx86custom**

Note I pulled a copy of the redist exe from my own Azure account, but you could also just include it in the same folder as your Dockerfile and ADD it from there.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 AS base

# Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x86 Redistributable.
ADD https://lqsts.blob.core.windows.net/temp/vc_redist_2015_3.x86.exe C:/vc_redist.x86.exe
RUN C:\vc_redist.x86.exe /install /norestart /quiet /log vc_log.txt
```

**Add .NET Core SDK x86: waptx86corecustom**

```
# escape=`

# Installer image
FROM acswebwapt.azurecr.io/waptx86custom AS installer

# Apply latest patch
RUN curl -fSLo patch.msu http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2020/01/windows10.0-kb4534119-x64_a2dce2c83c58ea57145e9069f403d4a5d4f98713.msu `
    && mkdir patch `
    && expand patch.msu patch -F:* `
    && del /F /Q patch.msu `
    && DISM /Online /Quiet /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\patch\windows10.0-kb4534119-x64.cab `
    && rmdir /S /Q patch

ENV COMPLUS_NGenProtectedProcess_FeatureEnabled 0

RUN \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen uninstall "Microsoft.Tpm.Commands, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=amd64" `
    && \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen update `
    && \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen update

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]

# Retrieve .NET Core SDK
RUN $dotnet_sdk_version = '3.1.201'; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile dotnet.zip https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/$dotnet_sdk_version/dotnet-sdk-$dotnet_sdk_version-win-x86.zip; `
    $dotnet_sha512 = '48aa1afaf7a52effb367bbb14a66e2c3bf8da468025795daf0fa0d18e3b9650ba3bd23800c9965a4d4ec1d891afecbce51b2487730f1b0d6040ee7cb73a15ec6'; `
    if ((Get-FileHash dotnet.zip -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $dotnet_sha512) { `
        Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
        exit 1; `
    }; `
    `
    Expand-Archive dotnet.zip -DestinationPath dotnet; `
    Remove-Item -Force dotnet.zip

# Install PowerShell global tool
RUN $powershell_version = '7.0.0'; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile PowerShell.Windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg https://pwshtool.blob.core.windows.net/tool/$powershell_version/PowerShell.Windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg; `
    $powershell_sha512 = '1980da63a4f6017235e7af810bfda66be8fa53d0475d147a8219a36c76a903af99adb6cd5309e3dadc610389ae3525bca1ca2d30e7a991640e924334fd4e4638'; `
    if ((Get-FileHash PowerShell.Windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg -Algorithm sha512).Hash -ne $powershell_sha512) { `
        Write-Host 'CHECKSUM VERIFICATION FAILED!'; `
        exit 1; `
    }; `
    `   
    \dotnet\dotnet tool install --add-source . --tool-path \powershell --version $powershell_version PowerShell.Windows.x64; `
    \dotnet\dotnet nuget locals all --clear; `
    Remove-Item -Force PowerShell.Windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg; `
    Remove-Item -Path \powershell\.store\powershell.windows.x64\$powershell_version\powershell.windows.x64\$powershell_version\powershell.windows.x64.$powershell_version.nupkg -Force


# SDK image
FROM acswebwapt.azurecr.io/waptx86custom

ENV `
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true `
    ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:443;http://+:80 `
    # Enable correct mode for dotnet watch (only mode supported in a container)
    DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true `
    # Skip extraction of XML docs - generally not useful within an image/container - helps performance
    NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip `
    # PowerShell telemetry for docker image usage
    POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL=PSDocker-DotnetCoreSDK-NanoServer-1909

# In order to set system PATH, ContainerAdministrator must be used
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet;C:\Program Files\powershell"
USER ContainerUser

COPY --from=installer ["/dotnet", "/Program Files (x86)/dotnet"]

COPY --from=installer ["/powershell", "/Program Files/powershell"]

# Trigger first run experience by running arbitrary cmd
RUN dotnet help
```

**Add application**

```
FROM acswebwapt.azurecr.io/waptx86corecustom AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM acswebwapt.azurecr.io/waptx86corecustom AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WAPTCoreWebService/WAPTCoreWebService.csproj", "WAPTCoreWebService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WAPTCoreWebService/WAPTCoreWebService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WAPTCoreWebService"
RUN dotnet build "WAPTCoreWebService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WAPTCoreWebService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WAPTCoreWebService.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.  The Windows base image does not have .NET Core installed.  There is documentation on how to install .NET Core in a Docker image here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/snippets/installing-dotnet.md.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Based on the link I created a custom base image that seems to be kind of working (see updates in original question), but I still get the "Unable to start program: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe." when running from VS.  Any ideas?